# What can cause a JS Event Listeners Leak in ajax jquery calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval, event-listener

I put this code in a setInterval() when I look at the performance monitor in chrome I get an constant increase in JS Event Listeners  (+2 every call)

Is this a normal behaviour ?

```
setInterval(function(){
 $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function (request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + id_token);

    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://example.com/api/v1/foo',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function (error) {

    }
  })
}, 1000)
```

using jQuery : 2.1.1

FYI : I'm using a template for my UI, can it be some override of the ajax call ? somewhere ?

[image: First snapshot]
[image: After 22 seconds]

Comment: As it stands there's not enough information. I'm guessing there's something in `cb`  or the rest of the function the AJAX request is getting fired from. Could you add relevant code to help us answer your question

Comment: @phuzi : I don't have a cb in this case (my cb is not defined) so even without a cb .. it's still increasing, I'll edit the question

Comment: my bet is that you are setting interval and not clearing it. So after some fixed amount of time a new event listener is created.

Comment: @redFur: I usually not use setInterval() I use setTimeout Instead if I get a response from the ajax call ... but in this particular case I run it in the console and I had the JS event Listeners increasing

Comment: You say "+2 every call" how do you count that?

Comment: An "increase in JS event listeners"? Of which there are none here, so what are you talking about instead?

Comment: @DaveNewton `$.ajax` internally must use an event listener for the `readystatestange` event.

Comment: @Paulpro That's true.

Comment: @M.Gara Does the call complete in < 1sec? Are you stacking up Ajax calls?

Answer (score 0):

Can't find the article i was looking for.
But it is recommend to use ("setTimeout") over setInterval for functions that might take awhile to run.

SetTimeout does not hangup other scripts.
SetInterval waits until the function is complete or something like that.  This will cause a delay or pause of other scripts running properly.